# Elastic NEST Client how to sort by on a nested property

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, asp.net-core-5.0

As a newbie to NEST Library, pulling my hair out with the documentation that's making no sense to me at all.

First Issue: Cannot figure out how to map the results from a query to a strongly type model, despite having captured the json result and pasting to a C# class, what ever I try, unless I use a dynamic type in the query method then the results return null.

Model derived from the json result returned from the query:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public int took { get; set; }
    public bool timed_out { get; set; }
    public _Shards _shards { get; set; }
    public Hits hits { get; set; }
}

public class _Shards
{
    public int total { get; set; }
    public int successful { get; set; }
    public int skipped { get; set; }
    public int failed { get; set; }
}

public class Hits
{
    public Total total { get; set; }
    public float max_score { get; set; }
    public Hit[] hits { get; set; }
}

public class Total
{
    public int value { get; set; }
    public string relation { get; set; }
}

public class Hit
{
    public string _index { get; set; }
    public string _type { get; set; }
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public float _score { get; set; }
    public _Source _source { get; set; }
}

public class _Source
{
    public DateTime timestamp { get; set; }
    public string level { get; set; }
    public string messageTemplate { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public Fields fields { get; set; }
}

public class Fields
{
    public string LogEventCategory { get; set; }
    public string LogEventType { get; set; }
    public string LogEventSource { get; set; }
    public string LogData { get; set; }
    public string MachineName { get; set; }
    public int MemoryUsage { get; set; }
    public int ProcessId { get; set; }
    public string ProcessName { get; set; }
    public int ThreadId { get; set; }
}
```

Sample JSON result returned from query:

```
{
  "took" : 16,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 8,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "webapp-razor-2021.05",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "n2tbTnkBwE4YgJowzRsT",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "@timestamp" : "2021-05-09T00:41:47.2321845+01:00",
          "level" : "Information",
          "messageTemplate" : "{@LogEventCategory}{@LogEventType}{@LogEventSource}{@LogData}",
          "message" : "\"WebApp-RAZOR\"\"Application Startup\"\"System\"\"Application Starting Up\"",
          "fields" : {
            "LogEventCategory" : "WebApp-RAZOR",
            "LogEventType" : "Application Startup",
            "LogEventSource" : "System",
            "LogData" : "Application Starting Up",
            "MachineName" : "DESKTOP-OS52032",
            "MemoryUsage" : 4713408,
            "ProcessId" : 15152,
            "ProcessName" : "WebApp-RAZOR",
            "ThreadId" : 1
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "webapp-razor-2021.05",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "oGtdTnkBwE4YgJowuxu_",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "@timestamp" : "2021-05-09T00:43:54.0326968+01:00",
          "level" : "Information",
          "messageTemplate" : "{@LogEventCategory}{@LogEventType}{@LogEventSource}{@LogData}",
          "message" : "\"WebApp-RAZOR\"\"Application Startup\"\"System\"\"Application Starting Up\"",
          "fields" : {
            "LogEventCategory" : "WebApp-RAZOR",
            "LogEventType" : "Application Startup",
            "LogEventSource" : "System",
            "LogData" : "Application Starting Up",
            "MachineName" : "DESKTOP-OS52032",
            "MemoryUsage" : 4656048,
            "ProcessId" : 12504,
            "ProcessName" : "WebApp-RAZOR",
            "ThreadId" : 1
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "webapp-razor-2021.05",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "oWtgTnkBwE4YgJownRtc",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "@timestamp" : "2021-05-09T00:47:02.8954368+01:00",
          "level" : "Information",
          "messageTemplate" : "{@LogEventCategory}{@LogEventType}{@LogEventSource}{@LogData}",
          "message" : "\"WebApp-RAZOR\"\"Application Startup\"\"System\"\"Application Starting Up\"",
          "fields" : {
            "LogEventCategory" : "WebApp-RAZOR",
            "LogEventType" : "Application Startup",
            "LogEventSource" : "System",
            "LogData" : "Application Starting Up",
            "MachineName" : "DESKTOP-OS52032",
            "MemoryUsage" : 4717560,
            "ProcessId" : 17952,
            "ProcessName" : "WebApp-RAZOR",
            "ThreadId" : 1
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

2nd Issue: I'm trying to sort by a property that is nested within the JSON, an example being the property called "LogEventCategory"

NEST Client method:

```
var searchResponse = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<dynamic>(s => s
   .RequestConfiguration(r => r
        .DisableDirectStreaming()
    )
    //.AllIndices()
   .From(0) // From parameter defines the offset from the first result you want to fetch.
   .Size(3) // Size parameter allows you to configure the maximum amount of hits to be returned.
   .Index("webapp-razor-*")
   //.Index("index-1,index-2")
   .Query(q => q
        .MatchAll()
    )
    .Sort(so => so
         .Field(fs => fs
             //.Field("@timestamp") // this one seems to work
             .Field("logEventCategory")
             .Order(SortOrder.Ascending)
             //.Order(ColumnSortOrder)
          )
    )
);
```

Knowing that NEST High Level Client is designed to map against proper models, I realise using dynamic type is not correct, but I just can't figure our why using a class that was created/mapped directly from a sample json response is still not working and that the result returned when doing so just gives me null values for the first few properties.

Example below where only the first few items are seen (but still null)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First Issue: Cannot figure out how to map the results from a query to a strongly type model, despite having captured the json result and pasting to a C# class, what ever I try, unless I use a dynamic type in the query method then the results return null.

> Model derived from the json result returned from the query:

You don't need to define models for the entire JSON response; the client will take care of correctly deserializing *most* of the response, so the only POCO that needs to be created is for the `_source` JSON object. Based on the example provided, this would be something like

```cs
public class LogMessage
{
    [PropertyName("@timestamp")]
    public DateTimeOffset Timestamp { get; set; }
    
    public string Level {get;set;}
    
    public string MessageTemplate {get;set;}
    
    public string Message {get;set;}
    
    public Dictionary<string, object> Fields {get;set;}
}
```

We can check to see if this deserializes correctly by creating a stub response and passing it to the client to deserialize

```cs
private static void Main()
{
    var defaultIndex = "default_index";
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));

    var json = @"{
  ""took"" : 16,
  ""timed_out"" : false,
  ""_shards"" : {
        ""total"" : 1,
    ""successful"" : 1,
    ""skipped"" : 0,
    ""failed"" : 0
  },
  ""hits"" : {
        ""total"" : {
            ""value"" : 8,
      ""relation"" : ""eq""
    
    },
    ""max_score"" : 1.0,
    ""hits"" : [
      {
            ""_index"" : ""webapp-razor-2021.05"",
        ""_type"" : ""_doc"",
        ""_id"" : ""n2tbTnkBwE4YgJowzRsT"",
        ""_score"" : 1.0,
        ""_source"" : {
                ""@timestamp"" : ""2021-05-09T00:41:47.2321845+01:00"",
          ""level"" : ""Information"",
          ""messageTemplate"" : ""{@LogEventCategory}{@LogEventType}{@LogEventSource}{@LogData}"",
          ""message"" : ""\""WebApp-RAZOR\""\""Application Startup\""\""System\""\""Application Starting Up\"""",
          ""fields"" : {
                    ""LogEventCategory"" : ""WebApp-RAZOR"",
            ""LogEventType"" : ""Application Startup"",
            ""LogEventSource"" : ""System"",
            ""LogData"" : ""Application Starting Up"",
            ""MachineName"" : ""DESKTOP-OS52032"",
            ""MemoryUsage"" : 4713408,
            ""ProcessId"" : 15152,
            ""ProcessName"" : ""WebApp-RAZOR"",
            ""ThreadId"" : 1

          }
            }
        },
      {
            ""_index"" : ""webapp-razor-2021.05"",
        ""_type"" : ""_doc"",
        ""_id"" : ""oGtdTnkBwE4YgJowuxu_"",
        ""_score"" : 1.0,
        ""_source"" : {
                ""@timestamp"" : ""2021-05-09T00:43:54.0326968+01:00"",
          ""level"" : ""Information"",
          ""messageTemplate"" : ""{@LogEventCategory}{@LogEventType}{@LogEventSource}{@LogData}"",
          ""message"" : ""\""WebApp-RAZOR\""\""Application Startup\""\""System\""\""Application Starting Up\"""",
          ""fields"" : {
                    ""LogEventCategory"" : ""WebApp-RAZOR"",
            ""LogEventType"" : ""Application Startup"",
            ""LogEventSource"" : ""System"",
            ""LogData"" : ""Application Starting Up"",
            ""MachineName"" : ""DESKTOP-OS52032"",
            ""MemoryUsage"" : 4656048,
            ""ProcessId"" : 12504,
            ""ProcessName"" : ""WebApp-RAZOR"",
            ""ThreadId"" : 1

          }
            }
        },
      {
            ""_index"" : ""webapp-razor-2021.05"",
        ""_type"" : ""_doc"",
        ""_id"" : ""oWtgTnkBwE4YgJownRtc"",
        ""_score"" : 1.0,
        ""_source"" : {
                ""@timestamp"" : ""2021-05-09T00:47:02.8954368+01:00"",
          ""level"" : ""Information"",
          ""messageTemplate"" : ""{@LogEventCategory}{@LogEventType}{@LogEventSource}{@LogData}"",
          ""message"" : ""\""WebApp-RAZOR\""\""Application Startup\""\""System\""\""Application Starting Up\"""",
          ""fields"" : {
                    ""LogEventCategory"" : ""WebApp-RAZOR"",
            ""LogEventType"" : ""Application Startup"",
            ""LogEventSource"" : ""System"",
            ""LogData"" : ""Application Starting Up"",
            ""MachineName"" : ""DESKTOP-OS52032"",
            ""MemoryUsage"" : 4717560,
            ""ProcessId"" : 17952,
            ""ProcessName"" : ""WebApp-RAZOR"",
            ""ThreadId"" : 1

          }
            }
        }
    ]
  }
}";

    // create a connection that always returns the above response
    var connection = new InMemoryConnection(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));

    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool, connection)
        .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex);
        
    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    // actually doesn't matter what query we send through as we'll always get the stubbed response
    var searchResponse = client.Search<LogMessage>(s => s);
    
    foreach (var document in searchResponse.Documents)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{document.Timestamp} {document.Message}");
    }
}
```

which yields

```
9/05/2021 12:41:47 AM +01:00 "WebApp-RAZOR""Application Startup""System""Application Starting Up"
9/05/2021 12:43:54 AM +01:00 "WebApp-RAZOR""Application Startup""System""Application Starting Up"
9/05/2021 12:47:02 AM +01:00 "WebApp-RAZOR""Application Startup""System""Application Starting Up"
```

> 2nd Issue: I'm trying to sort by a property that is nested within the JSON, an example being the property called "LogEventCategory"

In `LogMessage` POCO, the `fields` are mapped as a `Dictionary<string,object>` as I guess the key/values can be dynamic. To sort on a property in this object would be

```cs
var searchResponse = client.Search<LogMessage>(s => s
    .Sort(so => so
        .Ascending(f => f.Fields["LogEventCategory"])
    )
);
```

which yields the following request

```json
POST http://localhost:9200/default_index/_search?pretty=true&typed_keys=true 
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "fields.LogEventCategory": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If Elasticsearch has inferred the mapping for `LogEventCategory` i.e. no explicit data type mapping was provided for it, then it'll be mapped as a [`text`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html) field with a [`keyword`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) [multi-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) (or sub-field). Attempting to sort on a `text` field where [`fielddata`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html#fielddata-mapping-param) has not been enabled (it's disabled by default) will result in an error. One typically should use a `keyword` field for sorting and aggregations, so if the mapping has been inferred, the `keyword` multi-field can be targeted for the sorting with

```cs
var searchResponse = client.Search<LogMessage>(s => s
    .Sort(so => so
        .Ascending(f => f.Fields["LogEventCategory"].Suffix("keyword"))
    )
);
```

Comment: Many thanks Russ, appreciate the time you put into the detailed answer. The fundamental part I was missing was the fact I hadn't specified the "fields" object as a type Dictionary in my C# Model Class. Using type Dictionary hopefully means I wont need to worry about the inner properties as these may change slightly between my different apps that are using Serilog, given I'm not logging with the same structured log event properties between all apps.

Comment: I have also started to look at the Elastic lower level client as well now as I believe it may easier to compile queries that will be more dynamic depending on how many filters the user wants to apply at the time of the search. With NEST, it looks to be that all queries are hard coded by the nature of the query syntax, so less flexibility than perhaps using some custom JavaScript to compile the query before sending to the server to process.

Comment: The low level client offers a more bare bones approach to formulating requests, with one able to pass JSON strings as queries, however, I would recommend starting with NEST, which would allow the construction of queries with types or expressions. For fields, NEST can be passed strings, and for varying document structures, one can use a more dynamic structure like `JObject` (in conjunction with `JsonNetSerializer`). Take a look at the example walkthrough for some ideas on how to construct more complex queries: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net-example